# How can this MySQL query be optimized

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

Given the following table structure

```
images                 data
 ------------------    ----------------------------------
| id    | filename |  | fromImageId | toImageId | result |
 ------------------    ----------------------------------
```

I have the following `SELECT` to get all `images.filename` that do not have an entry in `data` (either `fromImageId` or `toImageId`)

```
SELECT image.id, image.filename
FROM images image
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT fromImageId, toImageId
    FROM data results
    WHERE fromImageId = image.id
        OR toImageId = image.id
) ORDER BY image.id
```

As the `data` table is quite large (500,000+) this query takes a very long time to compute (around 10-15 seconds).

I'm very sure there is much optimization to be done here, but I can't quite get my head around what I could do to optimize the query.

PS: `images.id` is a `PRIMARY KEY` and both `fromImageId` and `toImageId` are `FOREIGN KEY`s on `images.id`

Comment: Do you have Indexes on the fromImageId and toImageId columns?

Comment: I'm always leery of the efficiency of `OR` clauses in SQL. Maybe try rewriting this as two queries, one for fromImage and one for toImage and then intersecting the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ensure your "Data" table has AT LEAST two indexes... One on just the FROM image id, the other on To Image ID.  Then, slightly different than Michael was proposing

```
select STRAIGHT_JOIN
      i.ID,
      i.FileName
   from
      Images i
         LEFT JOIN Data d1
            on i.ID = d1.FromImageID
         LEFT JOIN Data d2
            on i.ID = d2.ToImageID
   where
          d1.FromImageID is null
      AND d2.ToImageID is null
```

With the two individual indexes, this query starts with you image file and gets lined-up with TWO versions of your Data table... respectively joined by EITHER from or to image values AT THE SAME TIME.  So now, it should just blow through and kick out only those entries where BOTH "Data" tables DONT find a match.

Comment: This is amazing. Every other query took around 10-15 seconds, this ones maximum was just under 20ms. Amazing!

Comment: Just one question to understand it correctly; what does the `STRAIGHT_JOIN` do? Is it necessary and if yes, why?

Comment: @florianpeschka, see my other link for clarification...    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936532/mysql-query-performance-help-many-of-the-same-table-being-joined/9952793#9952793

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
    images.id,
    filename
FROM
    images
LEFT JOIN `data` ON images.id = fromImageId
OR images.id = toImageId
WHERE
    fromImageId IS NULL AND toImageId IS NULL
```

And ensure indexes are on `fromImageId` and `toImageId`.

Comment: `data` doesn't have an `id`-field

Comment: So it doesn't. I've changed my answer to reflect that. I don't know if the `*ImageId`s can be `NULL` so I've had to make sure both of them are `NULL` (because they can't both be `NULL` and join to the `images` table (assuming that `images.id` can't be `NULL`)).

Answer (score 0):

NOT IN might be a better choice. Haven't tested it, but please try the following

```
SELECT image.id, image.filename
FROM images image
WHERE image.id NOT IN(
    SELECT IFNULL(fromImageId, toImageId)
    FROM data results
    WHERE fromImageId = image.id
        OR toImageId = image.id
) ORDER BY image.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way I can think of forming this query is:

```
SELECT image.id, image.filename
FROM images image
WHERE image.id NOT IN(
    SELECT fromImageId, toImageId
    FROM data results
) ORDER BY image.id
```

don't really know about the "optimization" it will do, but maybe you should think of making this a **Stored Procedure**.